# ebpf program to prevent VSCode server from running

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ebpf

I have to manage a Linux host with ssh enabled on it. It's a jump host and it's not supposed to be used for anything else other than for getting into a secure network. The problem is I have noticed users using it as dev box by running VSCode server (remote ssh mode) on it. The binary that VSCode seems to be running remotely is code-server. Is it possible to create a ebpf program that gets called when a new process is created, such that the program checks the binary name and fails the fork?

Comment: If you are only using SSH for the jumphost you can just disable all other types of access via the sshd config. For example: https://goteleport.com/blog/ssh-jump-server/ that is way more practical

Answer (score 0):

Not with eBPF, but this [SystemTap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) script should work just as well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stap
probe kprocess.exec {
    if (isinstr(filename, "vscode-server")) {
        printk(7, sprintf("user %d is exec'ing %s\n", uid(), filename))
        raise(9);
    }
}
```